# I don't want to use "instanceof" in java , what do I do?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have two abstract classes called `Robot` and `GeometricElement`.
Each one of them has subclasses.
I need to build a matrix of NxM that holds either a `Robot` or a `GeometricElement`, so 
I've written another class and called it `Item`, and then `Robot` and `GeometricElement`
inherit from that class.

Here is the code:

```
public class Item {
    private Dot currentLocation;
    private boolean taken;

    public Item(Dot location) {
        int x = location.getXcomponent();
        int y = location.getYcomponent();
        currentLocation = new Dot(x,y);
        taken = false;
    }

    // more code 
}

public abstract class GeometricElement extends Item {

    private float area; 

    public GeometricElement(Dot location) {
        super(location);
    }
}


public abstract class Robot extends Item { 
    private float basketArea;

    /*  Constructor */

    public Robot(Dot location, float basketNewArea) {
        super(location);
        basketArea = basketNewArea;
    }

    // some more code 
}
```

The class that takes care of storing the `Item`s is called Ground :

```
public class Ground {

    private Item[][] board;
    private Queue elementQueue;

    /*  Constructor */

    public Ground(int row,int col) {
        board = new Item[row][col];
        this.elementQueue = new Queue();
    }

    // more code 

    public void addElementsToRobot() {
        while (this.elementQueue.doesQueueHasItems()) {
            GeometricElement element = elementQueue.popElementFromQuque();
            int x = element.getXlocation();
            int y = element.getYlocation();
            if (this.board[x][y].isTaken()) {
                if (board[x][y] instanceof Robot) {
                    // add geometric element to the basket
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, I need to store a `Robot` or a `GeometricElement` in the board. The problem starts when I try to read from the matrix (the 'board' matrix in 'Ground'): I can't seem to find a way to tell if I have in a cell either a Robot or a GeometricElement, without using `instanceof`.

Comment: WHy do you need to know whether you have a `Robot` or a `GeometricElement`?  The whole point of extending a base class is to avoid the need to explicitly check.

Comment: Why don't you want to use instanceof? It seems to be the most logical in your case.

Comment: Because a Robot has the ability to add a GeometricElement to a Basket (sorry for not mentioning this earlier) .

Comment: @ron: If you want access to only the `Robot` instances, you probably shouldn't be maintaining a container of generic `Item`s.  The whole point of using base classes is when you can happily say "I don't care".

Comment: Oli ,I don't have a choice here.That's the assignment's rules : use a matrix of NxM , and store the Robot/GeometricElement in it.I think you are indeed right ,but I have no choice here.

Comment: That's homework questions for you. Sometimes they are stupid... "Those that can't teach".  The thing that's bad is not really the instanceof, but the cast.  Instance of, just checks that the cast is safe.  The best suggestion is to add a more generic `void interact(Item otherItem)` to the Item class which does nothing by default, then override it in the Robot to pick up whatever's there.  EDIT: if the robot can only pick up GeometricElement, then you're back to using instance of in the robot method though.  Sometimes in homework questions you just cant use good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your goals of course, but from the top of my head:

I would personally refactor this using Composite pattern, so that you can access all elements in a uniform fashion. And as for determining without instance of, you can have an abstract method on your Item class telling each other apart. Or you could have public property doing that. Or you could come with better design.

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Instanceof may be actually a solution to your problem but generally, it points to deeper design issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives, using the `Class` object returned by `Object.getClass()`:

- Use `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)` to test if the `Class object` is a subclass of (say) `Robot`.
- Compare it with the `Class` objects for the leaf classes.
- Do some stuff with the String returned by `Class.getName()`, etcetera.

Or you could add an abstract method `boolean isARobot()` to the `Item` class.

Or you could define an `enum` whose values denote the direct subclasses of `Item`.

However, these are all doing pretty much the same thing as `instanceof` ... so (IMO) you haven't achieved anything.  Certainly, you haven't removed the "code smell" of using `instanceof`.

Comment: Yes, the abstract method and the enum are arguably **more** smelly than the `instanceof`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - they **all** are more smelly, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of using the Composite design pattern. Very elegant :)

A less elegant (but faster - may be desirable, depending on when your homework's due) way would be to manage two matrices, one for Robots and one for GeometricObjects.

Using those, you could easily determine whether the Item at the given coordinates is one or the other by checking which matrix has that field occupied.

You'd have to be careful to avoid having something on those coordinates in both matrices, though.

As I said, much less elegant, but still no instanceof :)

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is homework, 'instanceof' is the simplest, and therefore probably the best way to go, even though it's not at all object-oriented, and is definitely a code smell.

One, more advanced way to do this is with 'double dispatch', a.k.a. The Visitor Pattern. There's a pretty good explanation at http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip98.html

Answer (score 0):

Definitively my recommendation is that you MUST use instanceof.

But an alternative may be:

```
 Object obj = ... //Robot or GeometricElement
 try {
     Robot robot =  (Robot) obj;
     // Do your logic for robot here
 } catch (ClassCastException ex){
     GeometricElement ge = (GeometricElement) obj;
     // Do your logic for geometric element here
 }
```

Comment: Um, I would think that exception catching should not be used in this way. I mean, exception is something irregular, you don't want to happen but try to solve. In his case however, he knows what to expect. I know you can do this, but I would consider it bad habit to say the least. It's the semantics, performance-wise, it's the same, by the way

Comment: @TomášPlešek you are right and it's because I recommend that he MUST use instanceof